# Maze Solver problems in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have now got it to stop repeating infinitely, but it just keeps trying the same wrong path over and over again. Does anyone know of a way to get it to try different paths?

Key for the numbers:
0 is open
1 is a wall
2 is part of the path
3 is the end of the maze

```
    public class Maze{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] maze = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}};
    boolean[][] posCheck = new boolean[maze.length][maze[0].length];
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++){
        if(maze[row][col]==0){
          r = row;
          c = col;
        }
      }
    }
    maze[r][c] = 3;
    mazeSolver(1, 0, maze, posCheck);
  }

  public static boolean mazeSolver(int r, int c, int[][]maze, boolean[][] posCheck){
    posCheck[r][c] = true;
    maze[r][c] = 2;

    if(maze[r][c] == 3){
      print(maze);
      return true;
    }

    if((c+1 < maze.length) && maze[r][c+1]==0 && !posCheck[r][c+1] && (mazeSolver(r, c + 1, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    if((r-1 >= 0) && maze[r-1][c]==0 && !posCheck[r-1][c] && (mazeSolver(r - 1, c, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    if((c-1 >= 0) && maze[r][c-1]==0 && !posCheck[r][c-1] && (mazeSolver(r, c - 1, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    if((r+1 < maze.length) && maze[r+1][c]==0 && !posCheck[r+1][c] && (mazeSolver(r + 1, c, maze, posCheck))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
      return true;
    }

    print(maze);
    return false;
  }

  public static void print(int[][] maze){
    for(int row = 0; row<maze.length; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col<maze[row].length; col++)
        System.out.print(maze[row][col]);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what do the numbers 0,1,2, and 3 mean

Comment: Maybe you should start with a smaller maze and work yourself up? This way you could spot errors more easily.

Comment: Even once you get this to recurse finitely, I foresee you running out of room on the stack passing an array that size upon each recursive call.

Comment: @Zéychin It's a reference to the array that is being passed, not the entire array.

Comment: After editing, you say it "doesn't work". How doesn't it work? Does it never finish executing? Does it finish but indicate it couldn't find a path? Does it give you a random path? Give us some more info than just "It doesn't work".

Comment: @GriffeyDog Oops! Reading over too many questions at once and mixed the contexts of several of them together. Yes, Java array references are passed, not entire arrays. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Dont ask same question 6 times,  you waste peoples time, yo ushould improve your question so people response to it

Answer (score 3):

I have added debugging output to every branch in your `mazeSolver` function. As you can see, no branch is ever being called, because the recursive call in the third if-block never finishes evaluating. It therefore is an infinite recursion, which is the cause of the `StackOverflowError`. It also shows that it is bouncing back and forth between only two different values, which is likely a problem.

You need to determine what your `mazeSolver` is actually doing--why that infinite recursion is never unrolling, and change it so one of the other conditions are met.

In other words, you need to fix your "recursion terminator", and figure out why no values other than [1, 1] and [0, 1] are being passed.

```
public static boolean mazeSolver(int r, int c, int[][] maze){
System.out.println("mazeSolver(" + r + ", " + c + ", maze)");

   if(maze[r][c] == 3)  {
System.out.println("  Equals 3 -- return true");
      return true;
   }  else if((c+1 < maze.length) && maze[r][c+1]==0 && (mazeSolver(r, c + 1, maze)))  {
      maze[r][c] = 2;
System.out.println("  Set to 2 (a) -- return true");
      return true;
   }  else if((r-1 >= 0) && maze[r-1][c]==0 && (mazeSolver(r - 1, c, maze)))  {
      maze[r][c] = 2;
System.out.println("  Set to 2 (b) -- return true");
      return true;
   }

System.out.println(" Between first and second if-block");


   if((c-1 >= 0 && maze[r][c-1]==0) && (mazeSolver(r, c - 1, maze)))  {
      maze[r][c] = 2;
System.out.println("  Set to 2 (c) -- return true");
      return true;
   }

System.out.println(" Between second and third if-block");

   if((r+1 < maze.length) && maze[r+1][c]==0 && (mazeSolver(r + 1, c, maze))){
      maze[r][c] = 2;
System.out.println("  Set to 2 (d) -- return true");
      return true;
   }

System.out.println("  return false");
   return false;
}
```

}

Output:

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava]java Maze
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
```

...and on and on...

```
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
mazeSolver(1, 0, maze)
mazeSolver(1, 1, maze)
 Between first and second if-block
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:64)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:82)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:69)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:82)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:69)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:82)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:69)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:82)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:69)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:82)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:69)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:82)
        at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:69)
    at Maze.mazeSolver(Maze.java:82)
```

...and on and on...

Comment: I have fixed the infinite recursion, but now it just keeps going through the same wrong path over and over again

Comment: So do something different. Add some more relevant debugging to help you. Add some *conditional* debugging, such as `if(someConditionIsTrue)  {  System.out.println("some relevant information");  }` so you're not overwhelmed by the output. You can also say `java Maze > temp.txt`, so you can analyze the output in a text editor. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of which positions you have already visited. A simple method would be to have a 2d boolean array of the same size as your maze, and to mark a position as true when your recursive method first hits it. In addition to your wall check, you'll want to add an wasVisited check.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm
http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/2/7/maze-generation-algorithm-recap

I have recently been writing a maze application and found the above sites extremely useful in gaining an understanding of the concepts. I created classes to represent Maze, Cell & edge to the graph as a collection of Cells (nodes) & Edges. At one point I also had a problem with not completing a search for a path & required better management of which cells had already been visited. I was repeatedly going back into a dead end as my algorithm didn't track that the Cell had already been visited. This sounds very similar to your problem.